# Handling of first aid questions

Tags: discussion

Inspired by this question [First aid: alternatives to hydrogen peroxide](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/27693/first-aid-alternatives-to-hydrogen-peroxide)

This question is built upon an inherently wrong premise, that hydrogen peroxide is the solution to their ailment. How should we handle questions like these? A medically inexperienced reader may not make it through all the comments/answers and walk away less able to medically respond than when they started. This is worrisome at best to me. I have edited in a header as a warning that the question may contain medically unsound advice and that one should read further. Is this something that is ok to do/encouraged?

The other issue with the question is that there is a potentially large difference between wilderness medicine and non-wilderness ("urban" even if not a city) medicine. Is there/should there be a process to distinguish between the two in questions? I don't know if tags are the best way or if we want to comment encouraging users to distinguish in their question. Otherwise we end up with two answers that are assuming different contexts (which we currently have in the above question) which to me is confusing for readers.

Answer (score 2):

I think you worked through this well in the chat discussion, and the OP was amenable to correction of their misconception. The outcome - having a headline warning above the post seems to work.

Additionally, if you wanted to, you could provide a link to specific documentation (eg if there is somewhere online that has medical guidance on the quantities of hydrogen peroxide for different tasks. I have used it to clean wounds, as has my wife (she is a nurse, I just like chemicals), and I have also used it in a model rocket engine and to bleach and etch things, so I am aware that it has very different effects at different strengths, and I think that sort of clarity in the post would help.